# User session IONIC 2

Tags: angular, session, ionic2

I'm trying to log an user, and get the data of this user in another page, but I have "undefined" everywhere...

My service :

```
 export class User {
   password: string;
   email: string;
   id:any;

  constructor(data) {
    this.id = data;
    return this.id;
  }

  getUser(){
  return this.id;
  }
}

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
```

login(value) {

```
let headers = new Headers({
'Content-Type':'application/json'
});
let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers
});
let body = value;

return new Promise(resolve=> {

  this.http
    .post(this.url+'/user/auth', body)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.user = new User(data);

          resolve(this.user);

          console.log(this.user);


            this.local = new Storage();
            this.local.set('User', this.user);
            this.local.get('User').then((val) => {
              console.log('You are', val)
            });

        });
});
```

}

Somewhere else in my code :

```
 public getUserInfo():User{
  console.log(this.user)
  return this.user;
 }
```

In home.ts :

```
 public test;  
 this.test = this.auth.getUserInfo();
```

Thank you for your help ! I've also tried to used Storage, but sometimes, the data is not shared between pages, so How can I use my User info ?

Comment: wher e exactly is login subscribed? without subscribe.. the http request will not be sent

Comment: I do the login() when a form is submitted. So, my 2 console.log inside .map are working, but not outside of the function.

Comment: The `http.post` is asynchronous. The data may not be set when you call `getUserInfo`. The only place where you are sure to get the data is in subscribe..

Comment: I've already tried this, but when I add a .subscribe, I get an error : Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: Where are you calling `getUserInfo`? can you add that part?

Comment: Of course : getUserInfo is a function inside my auth provider, so after my login() function, I have the getUserInfo(). After success of login, I am redirected to the home page, where I do a : public test;  this.test = this.auth.getUserInfo();

Comment: can you add that component code to the question

Comment: Ok, I had the part of the component in my code !

Comment: okk..that doesnt tell me much.. are you redirecting within subscribe? also.. where have you set auth as provider? is it singleton? you will have to put all relevant code else people cant tell where the issue is

Comment: I changed my code with what I've modified. My problem is still the same : my Class User is empty, even after the .subscribe !

Answer (score 7):

Your question being a bit vague as to where code is and in what order it's performed, I'll just provide an answer on how you could do this, using **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**, since you in your own words said you log in, you navigate to other page and then retrieve the user. First thing I noticed, is that you subscribe in your service, I suggest you do it in the component (your component where you login).

In your service you want to actually check the response if the user is authenticated, here I **won't** regard that though.

**AuthService:**

```ts
login(value) {
  // other code here
  this.http.post(this.url+'/user/auth', body)
    .map((res:Response) => {
      let resp = res.json();
      // set user in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(resp));
      return resp;
    });
}
```

Then you might want to have a method in the authService to return this user to the components requesting it:

```ts
getUser() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
}
```

So back to your login page, where you call your login method, so it could be something like this...

```ts
login(credentials) {
  this.authService.login(credentials)
    .subscribe(data => {
       // here user have already been saved to local storage and we can navigate
       this.router.navigate(['yourComponent']);
    });
}
```

And then in your component, after navigation, you just request this user in your `OnInit` and store it to a local variable in the component:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.authService.getUser();
}
```

With this, everything is chained properly:

1. Login
2. Http request
3. Store user in local storage from response
4. Navigate to other component
5. In the component retrieve user from local storage

Of course you do not need to use local storage, just check that your actions are chained properly.

Hope this helps! :)